# Trying to remove characters at the end of a string in three p elements using the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking to be able to use a class instead of an ID as I have three p elements that I need to remove 1- characters from. Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Initial reply thanks to Tim Down (and due to my very ropey explanation of what my problem was - shown below) I'm sure this is much easier than I know! Thanks.

```
<p id="test"> Nice text in here </p>

var textNode = document.getElementById("test").firstChild;
textNode.data = textNode.data.slice(0, -10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is tagged [`jquery`](http://api.jquery.com/). Maybe you're looking for:

```
$(".test").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().slice(0, -10));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers, you have the `document.getElementsByClassName` method available.  You can call this like this:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
for (var i = paras.length; i--;) {
    paras[i].firstChild.data = paras[i].firstChild.data.slice(0, -10);
}
```

However, not all browsers support this method.  You'll need to implement it yourself:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = paras.length; i--;) {
    if (/(?:^|\s)test(?:\s|$)/.test(paras[i].className)) {
        paras[i].firstChild.data = paras[i].firstChild.data.slice(0, -10);
    }
}
```

NB that this assumes you give the `p` elements the class `test`.

Comment: You should change your regex to `/(?:^|\s)test(?:\s|$)/`.  As it stands, it will match elements with a class of `not-a-test`, because dashes are non-word characters.  ;-)

Comment: @Ben Indeed. I don't know why I temporarily convinced myself that `-` was a word character.